# Object of type 'Submission#0+Payload[]' cannot be converted to type 'Submission#0+Payload[]' - C# Azure AppService

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

I have a C# AppService running on Azure with the following code snippet:

```
public static async Task<string> Run(Payload[] req, TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}

public class Payload
{
    public object registration { get; set; }
    public object _event { get; set; }
}
```

When I try and 'Save and Run', I get the following error log:

> Submission#0+Payload[]' cannot be converted to type 'Submission#0+Payload[]'

If I remove the '[]' from the parameter, click 'Save and Run', then put the array back in & save, it works but a huge nuisance. I'm just wondering if someone can spot something that I've done wrong, or should be doing better to fix this?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: @nilsK I'm getting an error that prevents me from saving my AppService. I don't want this error :)

Comment: Yes i got that :D ... but still. Forget everything you know from your project, then read your question again. Do you understand what OP is asking? We need context to help :s